# Anchor tag focus state inconsistent with browser default outline

Tags: css, focus

So I have an issue where I am trying to replace the outline option for a focus state with a new style.  Unfortunately it seems like the css :focus attribute isn't working the same as a the outline did.

Here is a quick example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mfeola/my8ngbow/

```
<a href="#">Test 1, no focus class</a>
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="focus">Test 2, with focus class</a>
```

If you click on the first link and hold down, you see the link turns to the default color for the browser (mine is red) but on the second when you do the same it is orange (from the css file present).  If you tab between the two links, the outline appears and color does not change on the first link, but it does on the second.

How can I style this without javascript so that they act the same but on tabing only, the color changes to orange?

### [image]

This is how it should work

[image]

---

Comment: Is requirement to change color of `a` element text when clicked ?

Comment: No, clicking should not change color.  Only tabbing should change the color.  That's where I'm stuck.  It's so simple yet it feels like I am missing something

Comment: The images affects appear different from actual `css` set at http://jsfiddle.net/mfeola/my8ngbow/8 ? Is requirement for a) outline of second element to change on `tab`, or b) text of second element to change on `tab` ? Describing requirement in words and referencing expected result of each element at Question would probably help users attempting solutions to Question. Not entirely clear, here, what expected result is for each element ?

Comment: I took out the second link because of the added confusion.  It was there to make the issue more apparent but I think the GIFs do that better. I keep trying to explain this issue without it being complicated because it really isn't  but its proving to be difficult.

Comment: Is requirement for second  element text color to be set to orange when it is selected using `tab` key ?

Comment: yes, thats the primary requirement, it should only change color when selected using tab key (which is how the outline operates)

Comment: Good Question. Not certain if requirement is possible using `:focus` . `:hover` does not appear able to override `:focus`

Comment: This can be solved by `:focus-visible` pseudo selector like `.focus:focus-visible{color:orange;}`. Theres not good bowser support in safari though.

Answer (score 0):

Like this? :)

```
.focus:focus {
    color:orange
}
```

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/my8ngbow/9/)

EDIT: Should be working as intended now :)

Comment: nope, if you use tab you see the focus outline appears.  I want the color to be active only when the focus outline appears without changing the focus outline

Comment: Okay, I'm not quite sure if I understand your question then, care to elaborate? I think @guest271314 is interested too.

Comment: I added a gif, basically the tabbing should be the only thing that changes the color of the link to orange, clicking on the element currently also changes it to orange and it should not

Comment: Same issue as mine, but I did add more information in my original post to help

Answer (score 0):

Use `:active`

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
a:active {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test 1, no focus class</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="focus">Test 2, with focus class</a>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/my8ngbow/2/

Comment: Nope, sorry.  I think you did the opposite.  It's a weird issue but basically I would like to see the color only change when tabbing through the links, not when clicking on.  I added a gif to help illustrate what I need.  I hope it helps

Comment: @MichaelF _"but basically I would like to see the color only change when tabbing through the links"_ Using `:focus` appears to render text as orange at https://jsfiddle.net/my8ngbow/3/ when `tab`  is pressed. What is purpose of `.focus` `class` ?

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the actual blue outline that borders `a` element on `:focus` ? , not the text ?

Comment: I posted another example and another gif that might help explain my point better

Comment: @MichaelF At `tab` of first element color of text should not change ?  At `tab` to second element, color of text should change ?